# display a limited number of items in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In the code below I display a list of all sites in a webapplication. I would like to show only a few sites, like 5 out of 100 for example, and below the list I would like to display a link which redirects the user to a page where he/she can view all the sites.

What is the best way achieve this? can anyone provide me with some code?

Thank you very much.

```
 public static WorkspacesList GetAll()
    {
        WorkspacesList allWorkspaces = new WorkspacesList();

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sng3sp6d:8888/"))
        {

            SPWebApplication webApplication = site.WebApplication;

            foreach (SPSite siteCollection in webApplication.Sites)
            {
                try
                {
                    SPWeb website = siteCollection.RootWeb;

                    if (website.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems))
                    {
                        allWorkspaces.Add(new Workspace(website.Title, website.Url, website.Created));
                    }

                }
                finally
                {
                    if (siteCollection != null)
                        siteCollection.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        allWorkspaces.Reverse();
        return allWorkspaces;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The *easiest* way to do this would be to put the list of site collections in a list and the use a standard web part to show the site collections that the user has access to.  You could then limit the number of items they see at a time.

You could also create a table dynamically with 5 rows in it and then just populate that table with the first 5 site collections. Add a button called "View All" that takes you to a page with the following:

Create a sharepoint list that holds your results - write all your results to the list, then add the list to a web part page.   let's call this page "/sites/mysite/siteassets/viewsites.aspx".

Code the "view all" button to take the user to the new page.  You can add the user id as a query string then filter the "viewsites" page by user id.

Answer (score 0):

Are you displaying this information in a WP, then u can have a configurable property of how many items you want to display - i.e. 5

Inspite of ForEach , you can use For and limit it to 5 rows.
On click on header you can redirect to another page > which has same WP configured to show all items.

Sandeep

Comment: Yes, I am using a web part. But how can you loop through the sites using the for loop? An example will be much appreciated

Comment: Thank you everyone for contributing to this thread, but I am using a Generic List to hold all the items. The requirement is that I display only the last 5 and the latest should be on top. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For performance issues; I'd suggest using SPSiteDataQuery and you can limit the items you get within the query.

Take a look at:

[SPSiteDataQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx) and 
[RowLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.rowlimit.aspx) property